# Realtek ALC269VB not playing sound on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

I have been trying hard to understand how to make my sound card to work again on my Ubuntu server 18.04
I have Codec: Realtek ALC269VB and I need it to work for my MPD server of which I have already installed.
I have alsamixer setup and everything is ON and with high volume.

```
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC269VB
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0269
Subsystem Id: 0x10280577
Revision Id: 0x100100
```

I have the card information above and I now need to have it work with linux.
trying cmus to play sounds and with no luck at all.. it shows the progress of playing the file but no sound is coming out the Speakers.
I also tried:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav
```

and the result not giving me an Error at all.. But still, No sound.

```
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

Following several instructions online [HdaIntelSoundHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto) I have setup the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

with the following :

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

And then `sudo alsa force-reload` with no luck at all..
I have also tried to put `realtek` instead of `auto` but with the same result - Nothing comes out from the speakers at all.

As instructed:

```
>> cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Result:
Codec: Realtek ALC269VB
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

That mean I have the Realtek ALC269VB Codec installed - what I need now is to make the magic happened and make the speakers works as well.
In the instructions it say:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=MODEL
```

But I don't know my model since following the page [HD-Audio-Models](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.19/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt) at line 63 I found that:

```
ALC269
======
laptop-amic   Laptops with analog-mic input
laptop-dmic   Laptops with digital-mic input
```

Nothing mentioning the VB and that I can use anything else. so I have put MODEL as auto

Now, Following the instructions:

```
>> cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0c/info
Result:
card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: CAPTURE
id: ALC269VB Analog
name: ALC269VB Analog
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 1
```

Means that I have card 0 and device 0 attached to that codec, and it is ALC269VB Analog and not the HDMI. so that should be the right one, correct?
Also tried to put the following as well : `options snd-hda-intel model=basic` with no luck at all.
forcing also to reload and rebooting - nothing!

I would be happy to get it back and running - i am not sure what i am doing wrong and I would be happy to get help from you experts.

Please assist!
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Please open "alsamixer" in a terminal session and tune "headphone". There is a bug still in linux kernal or alsa (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/697498).

My favorite solution (in german) is from https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kein-ton-am-internen-lautsprecher-nur-mit-kopf/4/ . All honor belongs to them.
There might be some other solution but my EeePC 1015px doesn't have HDMI.

1. Install ALSA tools

   - sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
2. Open retask tool

   - sudo -H hdajackretask
3. At "Internal Speaker, ATAPI"

   - mark "Override"
   - choose "Line out (Front)"
   - click at button "Install boot override"
   - reboot

Your speaker(s) should reproduce the sound again.

One caveat:
Your headphones will no longer switch the speakers off automatically.
Start "alsamixer" in a terminal to mute the speakers / the headphones with "m", by cursors you may navigate and increase/decrease volume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would be happy to know if it is for the Server without GUI as well? since I have mentioned that i am using the Server with no GUI and i am ONLY using CLI commands. How can I fix it with no GUI and only from CLI? 
You mention installing alst-tools-gui and it is around 250MB of installation, I am not sure that it is for the Ubuntu Server core without GUI - I would be happy if you correct me and that I am wrong. Thanks