# No sound on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound

I have a problem with sound on my device.Intel Tiger lake as processor and on everything works fine on Windows.

```
pactl info | grep '^Server Name'
Server Name: pulseaudio
inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: Huawei-D14 Kernel: 6.0.6-060006-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HUAWEI product: NBD-WXX9 v: M1010
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HUAWEI model: NBD-WXX9-PCB-B4 v: M1010 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: HUAWEI v: 2.30 date: 07/04/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.0.6-060006-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4An2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48b97.png)

Comment: Also trying to solve the same issue (on a MS Surface Studio 2, clean install sound is working in Windows). Did you try these solutions as well perhaps? Retaking the output: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234745/realtek-alc269vb-not-playing-sound-on-ubuntu-server-18-04 I have not solved it yet unfortunately.

Comment: this might help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451232/no-sound-on-huawei-14s-with-ubuntu-22-10

Answer (score 0):

some days before i had this same problem with pulseaudio.
1)first check the instance is running or not

```
pulseaudio --check
```

2. if it runs then kill that with following command.

   pulseaudio -k

3)after killing that try to start the pulseaudio again with

```
pulseaudio -D
```

4)in my case it is working

```
sudo service pulseaudio restart
```

Comment: Yeah thanks but still it dosen`t work

Comment: pulseaudio --check
aorio@Huawei-D14:~$ pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
aorio@Huawei-D14:~$ pulseaudio -D
aorio@Huawei-D14:~$ sudo service pulseaudio restart
Failed to restart pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not found.

Comment: #killall pulseaudio    then start the pulseaudio daemon like #pulseaudio -D

Comment: still nothing unfortunately